# Can I select which DVB-T audio channel VLC streams?

Tags: linux, streaming, vlc, dvb

Having a DVB-T stick working on Debian Wheezy, I am trying to stream DVB-T channels using VLC.

The streaming on server side works well. On the client I can open a stream by using URL http://my_ip:8080/tv_channel and I get video immediately.

The problem is, however, with audio tracks. On server side, VLC streams 2 audio tracks where the second one is the one I want to listen to.
However on client, VLC always defaults to first audio track.

Is there a way to either force server VLC to stream only the second track, or to tell the client via URL to use the second track?

What am trying to achieve is to open a link on client side and to have the right track used without a need to manually change it from first to second one.
Also, my mobile client cannot select audio stream, it always uses the first one.

Please note that some DVB-T channels have only single audio track while other have two. This means that setting second track as default in VLC client causes other channel to have audio disabled.

My server-side VLC config file:

```
new dvbt1 broadcast enabled
setup dvbt1 input "dvb-t://"
setup dvbt1 option dvb-adapter=0
setup dvbt1 option dvb-frequency=602000000
setup dvbt1 option dvb-bandwidth=8
setup dvbt1 option programs=513,514,770,773,2050
setup dvbt1 option ts-es-id-pid

setup dvbt1 output
#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/nova},select="program=513",
dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/nova-cinema},select="program=514",
dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/prima-cool},select="program=770",
dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/prima},select="program=773",
dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/barrandov-tv},select="program=2050"}

control dvbt1 play
```

Note: I already tried to manually select the `pid-audio` by adding this to config file, but this did actually nothing.

```
dst=std{access=http,mux=ts{pid-audio=112},dst=:8080/nova},select="program=513"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up using [MuMuDVB](http://www.mumudvb.net/) for unicast streaming which does the job just correctly - the primary channel is marked correctly as primary so that the player can use it by default.

Also, CPU footprint by MuMuDVB if far less than VLC.

Comment: What do you mean by command? I have MuMuDVB server started on the server, and the clients just connect to it's unicast address.